# macro define in foreach loop error

Tags: tikz-pgf

when I define \pluse macro and use it in foreach loop, then error reported:
code:

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\r{2}
 \def\plus{+(0.1,0) -- +(0.2,0.1) -- +(0.3,-0.1) -- +(0.4,0)}
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
 \draw[red,semithick,dashed,name path=arcafter] 
 (O) ++(\r,0) arc(0:-180:\r);
 \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
 {
      \draw[semithick,->,>=latex,name path=arrow] 
          (-\r,-\y*\r/4) -- (\r,-\y*\r/4);
      \draw[name intersections={
            of=arcafter and arrow,
            name=M,
            total=\t}] 
      foreach \i in {1,...,\t} 
      {
            (M-\i) ++(-0.2,0) \pluse
      };
 }
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

The error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@next ... \tikz@scan@next@command \pgf@let@token 

l.23  }

?
```

If replace the \pluse with the actual code, it works fine.
Not sure if anything wrong in my macro!

Comment: It's a typo `\pluse` vs.`\plus`.

Comment: There's also `foreach` instead of `\foreach`.

Comment: @Werner This is actually the cleaner way. If you replace `\pluse` by `\plus` or the other way around, you'll see that the code is fine.

Comment: @marmot: So are there `draw`, `coordinate`, ... equivalent versions? If not, it seems inconsistent, albeit cleaner.

Comment: @Werner you are right, my mistake! but I do not figure it out from error message!

Comment: @Werner Yes, please see the bottom of p. 902 of the pgfmanual, and, in particular the statement in section 14.14 "For historical reasons, you can also write \foreach instead of foreach."

Comment: @marmot: I see. That `foreach` forms part of a `\draw`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. There is only a typo. You define `\plus` but use `\pluse`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \def\r{2}
 \def\pluse{+(0.1,0) -- +(0.2,0.1) -- +(0.3,-0.1) -- +(0.4,0)}
 \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
 \draw[red,semithick,dashed,name path=arcafter] 
 (O) ++(\r,0) arc(0:-180:\r);
 \foreach \y in {0,...,4}
 {
      \draw[semithick,->,>=latex,name path=arrow] 
          (-\r,-\y*\r/4) -- (\r,-\y*\r/4);
      \draw[name intersections={
            of=arcafter and arrow,
            name=M,
            total=\t}] 
      foreach \i in {1,...,\t} 
      {
            (M-\i) ++(-0.2,0) \pluse
      };
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my mistake! but the error report not helpful to find the root cause!